# Stuck in Marathon 1 level 5

Tags: aleph-one, marathon

I have gotten to level 5 (Couch Fishing) in Marathon, where you have to flip 3 switches to prevent Durandal's access to that area. In the beginning Leela tells you where the switches are, but doesn't tell you what to do after that...

Is there a teleport terminal somewhere in the level that you have to reach after getting all the switches activated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to get to a specific comm terminal in one of the larger rooms on the map in order to finish, once you've completed the objective of flipping the switches.  There's a map on [this page](http://marathon.bungie.org/spoiler/m1/4.shtml) which may help you navigate the level:

[image]

Comment: That webpage basically tells you anything you need to know, ever, about any of the Marathon games.

Answer (score 1):

This is the terminal that you are looking for:

[image: Exit terminal for Couch Fishing]

Located two rooms *before* the three "switches" into which you plug the replacement circuits (that you obtained in the preceding level,  **Never Burn Money**).